# Bilinearly Blended Coons Patch

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I have four quintic Bézier curves and I want to create the Coons Surface that interpolates them. How can I obtain the 25 control points of the surface? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the control points of the surface are 36

Comment: I'm also trying to find out the answer. Here are some clues: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385277/subdividing-a-coons-patch