# Subdividing a Coons Patch

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

Given a Coons Patch, how could I subdivide the patch to create two seperate patches?

So far I've been able to subdivide the effected bezier curves using the Casteljau algorithm but I am unable to figure out how to generate the control points for the bezier curve between the two patches.

What I've tried so far is finding the average of the control points belonging to the curves on either side as well as just using equidistant points. While I can get a good approximation of the correct position in simple cases, this quickly breaks down based on how extreme the curve is.

Below is an example of the curves I am trying to generate by splitting a Coons patch. On the left you can the original bezier curves used to generate a sample Coons patch. On the right is an approximation of the new bezier curves needed to generate two adjacent Coons patches. So far I've been able to figure out the coordinates of all the positions outside the red circled area as well as the top and bottom most points inside the circle. The trouble I am having right now is figuring out the position of the two points in the center of the circled area.

[image: Coons Patch Example]

Comment: How is Coons surface defined in differential geometry? Is the mean curvature zero? If this known, the geometrical  goal is clear and  a finite difference method can be used for triangulation.

Comment: Did you delete your previous question?

Comment: @Rahul Yeah, sorry I was having some strange error with editing the question to add detail. Since I am on a bit of a deadline I decided to rewrite the question and delete the old one to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the parametric equation of the splitting curve. This is obtained by expliciting the Coons patch equation from the Bezier sides and freezing one of the parameters to $\frac12$.

Doing so, you will obtain a polynomial curve (if I am right, of degree one more than the initial Beziers). Then the X, Y and Z polynomials can be transformed to the Bernstein basis (by means of a linear transform), giving you the coordinates of the required control points.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm sure this is a solid answer but I should have mentioned I'm more of a programmer and less of a mathematician. If it's not too much trouble, can you provide an example to go along with your solution? I'll keep trying to figure it out on my end based on what you have described but it's going to take a while to verify your answer since I've got to look up almost every term.

Comment: Following what you first described, I was able to calculate the correct, or at least what I think is correct, control points for the above example. I wasn't really sure what to do when you mentioned Bernstein basis and transforming the equation but by evaluation the coons patch equation at u = 0.5 and then using the new equation to solve for v = 1/3 and v =  2/3 I was able to get two equations that I could use to solve for the missing control points. Hopefully if you have time to explain your answer a bit more I can come up with a general way to do this for any polynomial coons patch.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson: this might help you (though it is still a little technical): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61649/what-is-the-best-way-to-write-a-polynomial-in-the-bernstein-basis

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson: you can indeed choose $n$ values of $t$ and write a linear system of equations to identify the standard and Bernstein representations. E.g. $at^2+bt+c$ vs. $At^2+2Bt(1-t)+C(1-t)^2$. $$t=0\to c=C,\\ t=1/2\to a/4+b/2+c=A/4+B/2+C/4,\\ t=1\to a+b+c=A.$$ You can also proceed by expanding the Bernstein coefficients and identifying. You get an easy triangular system
$$a=A-2B+C, b=2B-2C, c=C.$$

Comment: Ah cool, thanks for the clarification. I think I managed to blunder my way into it over the last couple hours. I was able to create an algorithm that could generate the Bernstein equations and then solved them with a matrix. So far it's working great with all the test cases (probably a slow way of doing things) so I'll mark this correct. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson: thanks. The second formulation leads to a triangular system, so it is efficient (you have enough with the backsubstitution step of a full solver). You can as well precompute the matrix inverse, also triangular, for small degrees this is no problem. I suspect that there is a closed-form expression but I could not find it.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson: the useful relation is given in http://graphics.cs.ucdavis.edu/education/CAGDNotes/Bernstein-Polynomials.pdf, top of page 9.